# In Excel, How can I set up the indirect function to use its own cell address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 10 sheets and on the 11th sheet is my working sheet. In every cell I have an index match formula to output values between 1-10 to reference one of the original 10 sheets. I want to use the indirect function to fill sheet 11 with values from sheets 1 through 10.

For example the indexmatch formula outputs 3 in cell A1 so I want sheet 3 A1 , A2= sheet 7 A2, C3= sheet 1 C3 etc. How can I set up the indirect function to use its own cell address?

Comment: Do you mean `ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())`? Though there may be an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1

1. Use the index match + concatenate to build "SheetX!$A$1" string. hint: use `concatenate()` or `&`
2. get the current cell row number - 1 > `row()-1` & current cell column number - 1 > `column()-1`
3. Feed [1] & [2] into `offset()` formula.

Method 2

1. Use BigBen `ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())` formula
2. Use the index match + concatenate to build "SheetX!<cell_address_from_[1]>" string.
3. feed it to `indirect()` formula

Both should do. ( :

Comment: BigBen's method is what I ended up using, thanks to you both